# How do I remove last character from input field on click?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that when buttons are clicked, it enters a value into an input field. I want to add another button that deletes the last character added. How would I accomplish this using jQuery

Comment: what have you tried?  can you post an simple example of the page on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: do you mean a new character is attached at the end of your sting on each button click?

Comment: referthis from the stack-overflow itself. You have a good example too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string

Comment: so this is basically what I am doing so far.. http://jsfiddle.net/jeni/jfs4x/

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I'm sure they all worked great but arjuncc made it really simple!

Comment: you need to be lucky to get the "give me that code"

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper - huh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script>
function addTextTag(txt)
{
document.getElementById("text_tag_input").value+=txt;
}
function removeTextTag()
{
var strng=document.getElementById("text_tag_input").value;
document.getElementById("text_tag_input").value=strng.substring(0,strng.length-1)
}
</script>

<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

    <div class="tags_select">
    <a href="javascript:addTextTag('1')">1</a>
    <a href="javascript:addTextTag('2')">2</a>
    <a href="javascript:addTextTag('3')">3</a>
    <a href="javascript:removeTextTag()">delete</a>
</div>​
```

Used a modified version of your code itself try

Answer (score 3):

the simple answer is, if you are using jquery, to do something like this:

```
//select the button, add a click event
$('#myButtonId').on('click',function () { 
    //get the input's value
    var textVal = $('#myInputId').val();
    //set the input's value
    $('#myInputId').val(textVal.substring(0,textVal.length - 1));
});
```

Comment: If I try to use this, the console says `TypeError: textVal.length is not a function`

Comment: @CodyGuldner, yeah, that must've been a typo.  length is a property.

Comment: Oh duh. Shoulda caught that! Thanks! 1+ for being what I need!

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastChar = function (x) {
        "use strict";
        var a = document.getElementById(x),
            b = a.value;
        a.value = b.substring(0, b.length - 1);
    };
```

No jQuery required.  The x variable is the id of the input you want to mutilate.