# Removing last comma

Tags: javascript

I read content from a file and then write it another file after editing . While editing , for each read line i put a comma at the end of line and then write it to the file. For the last read line i do not want to write a comma. How should i do it.?

```
 while(!inputFile.AtEndOfStream){
    var readLine =  inputFile.ReadLine();
    var omitChars = new RegExp("#define").test(readLine);
    if(omitChars==1){
        var stringReadPosition = readLine.substr(8);
        var finalString = stringReadPosition.replace(/\s+/g, ': ');
              asd = outputFile.Write(finalString.replace(/^(_)/, "") + ",\r\n");
    }
 }
 outputFile.Write("};\r\n");
 inputFile.Close();
 outputFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: is this a `javascript` code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string)

Comment: You could try creating an array and adding outputFile.Write(finalString.replace(/^(_)/, "") as a new element within the while loop. Then outside the loop, use something like  [array].join(',\r\n')

Comment: Guambra feo has the perfect answer. Please submit it.

Comment: One trick is to output the comma and newline for the previous line at the beginning of the next line, except for the first line (which is easy to identify).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring` in order to remove the last character of the string after you have formed the string:

```
finalString = finalString.substring(0, finalString.length - 1);
```

An alternative would be the use of `slice`, taking into consideration that negative indices are relative to the end of the string:

```
finalString  = finalString.slice(0,-1);
```

Take a look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string) question for more.

UPDATE: For your case, you could check whether or not you have reached the EOF - meaning you have read the last line, and then apply `slice` or `substring`:

```
//....
var stringReadPosition = readLine.substr(8);
var finalString = stringReadPosition.replace(/\s+/g, ': ');

//Check if stream reached EOF.
if(inputFile.AtEndOfStream) {
    finalString  = finalString.slice(0,-1);
}
asd = outputFile.Write(finalString.replace(/^(_)/, "") + ",\r\n");
//....
```

Comment: The problem is that once it has come out of while loop , it has already written the last line . Now how do i Replace that last line written because answers suggested by you guys is writting the last line again

Comment: Answer updated with a relevant addition. Please consider selecting it as best if it is.

Answer (score 1):

try this asd = asd.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
this will remove last comma, I have tried this, its working .Check if it works in ur code.
Try this code inside while loop

Comment: The problem is that once it has come out of while loop , it has already written the last line . Now how do i Replace that last line written because answers suggested by you guys is writting the last line again