# How to stop add comma at last element of the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I stop adding comma when at last element such as this **ABC1** should not add comma.
[image: ArrayOutput] code sample here >>>[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-forest-j0pb4i?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:217-564)

```
  methods:{
    test(){
      this.Aarray.forEach((value)=>{
        this.Codes += value.Code +',';
      });
      console.log(this.Codes);
    }
  },
  data(){
    return{
      Codes:'',
      Aarray:[
        {Code:'ABC12345'},
        {Code:'ABC1234'},
        {Code:'ABC123'},
        {Code:'ABC12'},
        {Code:'ABC1'},
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.Aarray.join(',')`

Comment: also [Removing last comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098089/removing-last-comma) or [How to Remove last Comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047491/how-to-remove-last-comma) etc

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, we can simply slice off the final dangling comma.

```
methods: {
    test() {
        this.Aarray.forEach((value) => {
            this.Codes += value.Code +',';
        });
        console.log(this.Codes.slice(0, -1));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a separator variable:

```
methods: {
    test() {
        let sep = '';
        this.Codes = '';
        this.Aarray.forEach((value) => {
            this.Codes += sep value.Code;
            sep = ', ';
        });
        console.log(this.Codes);
    }
},
```

In this way separator can be complex.

HINT: I think `test()` must reset `this.Codes` everytime need to build up.