# How to split Unicode string to characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

For long time we used naive approach to split strings in JS:

```
someString.split('');
```

But popularity of emoji forced us to change this approach - emoji characters (and other non-BMP characters) like  are made of two "characters'.

```
String.fromCodePoint(128514).split(''); // array of 2 characters; can't embed due to StackOverflow limitations
```

So what is modern, correct and performant approach to this task?

Comment: I'm curious. Which StackOverflow limitations are you talking about?

Comment: It seems like I couldn't post question with result of `JSON.stringify(String.fromCodePoint(128514).split(''))` expression - it caused "Malformed URI" error thrown from jQuery and disallowed to post question.

Comment: @MrLister: [I have added Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274191/cant-post-result-alone-surrogates-because-of-jquery-raising-malformed-uri-bug).

Comment: see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode for the big picture

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Using [spread in array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) :

```js
const str = "";
console.log([...str]);
```

### Using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) :

```js
function split(str){
  const arr = [];
  for(const char of str)
    arr.push(char)
   
  return arr;
}

const str = "";
console.log(split(str));
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that this unfortunately still doesn't cover a lot of emojis currently in use. E.g. `[...'‍♀️']` becomes `["", "", "‍", "♀", "️"]`. Which means no e.g. straightforward string reversal or symbol-wise comparison is possible.

Comment: See https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter as an example library, mind the open issues regarding zero-width-joiners. Maybe there's a newer library out there.

Answer (score 10):

The best approach to this task is to use native `String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` that's aware of Unicode characters. Consequently clean and easy approach to split Unicode character is `Array.from` used on string, e.g.:

```
const string = String.fromCodePoint(128514, 32, 105, 32, 102, 101, 101, 108, 32, 128514, 32, 97, 109, 97, 122, 105, 110, 128514);
Array.from(string);
```

Comment: same, the `[...'‍♀️']` becomes `["", "", "‍", "♀", "️"]`

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript has a new API (part of ES2023) called [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) that allows you to split strings based on graphemes (the user-perceived characters of a string). With this API, your split might look like so:

```js
const split = (str) => {
  const itr = new Intl.Segmenter("en", {granularity: 'grapheme'}).segment(str);
  return Array.from(itr, ({segment}) => segment);
}
// See browser console for output
console.log(split('')); // ['']
console.log(split('é')); // ['é']
console.log(split('‍‍')); // ['‍‍']
console.log(split('❤️')); // ['❤️']
console.log(split('‍♀️')); // ['‍♀️']
```

```html
<p>See browser console for logs</p>
```

This allows you to not only deal with emojis consisting of two code points such as , but other characters also such as composite characters (eg: `é`), characters separated by ZWJs (eg: `‍‍`), characters with variation selectors (eg: ❤️), characters with emoji modifiers (eg: `‍♀️`) etc. all of which can't be handled by invoking the iterator of strings (by using spread `...`, `for..of`, `Symbol.iterator` etc.) as seen in the other answers, as these will only iterate the code points of your string.

Comment: Upvoted! Unfortunately [not supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter#browser_compatibility) as of this comment.

Answer (score 5):

A flag was introduced in ECMA 2015 to support unicode awareness in regex.

Adding `u` to your regex returns the complete character in your result.

```js
const withFlag = `ABDE`.match(/./ug);
const withoutFlag = `ABDE`.match(/./g);

console.log(withFlag, withoutFlag);
```

There's a little more about it [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)

Comment: same, `'‍♀️'.match(/./ug)` becomes `["", "", "‍", "♀", "️"]`

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this somewhere I had to support older browsers and a ES5 minifier, probably will be useful to other

```
    if (Array.from && window.Symbol && window.Symbol.iterator) {
        array = Array.from(input[window.Symbol.iterator]());
    } else {
        array = ...; // maybe `input.split('');` as fallback if it doesn't matter
    }
```