# remove last n letters from in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I check if one array contains arr  in JavaScript? Usually, I would expect a subString method, but there doesn't seem to be one. What is a reasonable way to check for this?

```
arr=["aaaaaa-2","bbbbbbbb-2","zzzz-3","ffddssaa-1","sssssss-3","areyo-1"]
```

i trying to remove last two characters from list, i tried with below code but no use of these, can any one suggest me

```
arr.substring(0, -2)
```

I need array like

```
["aaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","zzzz","ffddssaa","sssssss","areyo"]
```

Comment: arr.substring(0, -2) this will work, just modify arr[index].substring(0, -2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string)

Answer (score 3):

Just try with:

```
arr.map(function(v){
  return v.substr(0, v.length - 2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the elements and apply the **[`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** method, for that use  **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var arr = ["aaaaaa-2", "bbbbbbbb-2",, "zzzz-3", "ffddssaa-1", "sssssss-3", "areyo-1"];

var res = arr.map(function(v) {
  return v.substring(0, v.length-2);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=["aaaaaa-2","bbbbbbbb-2","zzzz-3","ffddssaa-1","sssssss-3","areyo-1"];

for(var i in arr){
  consile.log(arr[i].substr(0,arr[i].lastIndexOf("-")); //here is your value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use map method of array.

```
arr = arr.map(function(item){return item.slice(0, item.length-2)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].length-2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing would be to use `map` function

```
var arr=["aaaaaa-2","bbbbbbbb-2","zzzz-3","ffddssaa-1","sssssss-3","areyo-1"];
console.log(arr.map(function (e){
    return e.slice(0, -2);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all for your information `substring` method work on `string` not on `array` and here arr is an `array` the code should be like:-

```
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
   {
     arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].length-2);
   }
```