# I want to delete one letter at each click of the backspace key

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I delete each letter the textcontent of a paragraph element at each keydown on the backspace key button like the input field remove one letter at time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>repl.it</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p></p>
      <script>
         let p = document.querySelector("p")
         document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
           if(e.key === "Backspace"){
          p.textContent-=e.key;
         }else{
         p.textContent+=e.key
          }
          })

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `p.textContent-=e.key;` do `p.textContent = p.textContent.slice(0, -1);`.

Comment: Thanks brother that means alot.

Comment: @ahmedAli My pleasure :)

Comment: I am making an app are you in.

Comment: You answered my question once I solved it about my but still thank you.

Comment: @ahmedAli Is there a git repo for your app I can look up?