# Deleting a number of characters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to delete the last and not the initials, I did not find an idea, who is trying

```html
<p id="demo">I want to delete the last and not the initials, I did not find an idea, who is trying</p>

<script>
 document.getElementById("demo").innerText=
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText.replace(  /(.{10})/," " ); 

</script>
```

Comment: str = string.substring(0, string.length - 10);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<p id="demo">I want to delete the last and not the initials, I did not find an idea, who is trying</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerText=
 document.getElementById("demo").innerText.replace(  /(.{10})$/," " ); 
  
</script>
```