# remove some last characters

Tags: javascript, html

so I added a `prompt('Enter something);`. then for example I entered 'Hello world!' then I want this to have only 5 characters. So it will return 'Hello'. if I entered 'something', it will return 'somet'. how do I do that in JavaScript?

apologies if there's another question like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.slice`

```js
const input = prompt('Enter something');

alert(input.slice(0, 5))
```