# What the character is used in javascript to delete the last line when printing out

Tags: javascript

I've a function that print out this format:

```
{
"name": "Google",
"url": "https:/google.com"
}
,
{
"name": "Facebook",
"url": "https://wts-kalix.polystar.net/Kalix/#/portal/619551b520fbf40c1cf22bad/618419244a4be06500ba0e8a"
}
,
```

And i need to delete the last comma so that the JSON format become valid which character should i use when it prints out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/how-do-i-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string-using-javascript

Comment: Don't construct JSON's yourself. Make an array of objects and use `JSON.stringify()` for that. Too often things go wrong when you do it manually. (And then we get other questions here on Stack Overflow asking how to fix malformed JSON, which is near impossible.)

Comment: Is this your function or some third-party code you don't control? It feels weird to have a function that generates JSON yet produces slightly invalid output. Generating valid JSON at once is much easier than breaking it and repairing it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input to your formatter is an array, you can just use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), it does that automatically. You can in theory most likely also use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)